# Query Python logs in Glue Query with CloudWatch Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm very new to CloudWatch Insights, and I've been trying to understand how to get it to work with Python logging. Currently I have an `AWS Glue` ETL query setup in `PySpark/Python`. I am using the default `logging` package for Python in the script.

I've read the documentation, and I couldn't find any details as to how to format the logging that would make it query-able through CloudWatch Insights. Ideally, I would like to setup different fields in the log messages that I can query and get the values from through with Insights.

Here's an example of a logging message in the script:

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

...run some code

stop = timeit.default_timer()

runtime = stop - start

logging.info('Runtime: {}'.format(runtime))
```

I would want to query the custom field like `@Runtime` to show all the runtimes in that column for different runs. With this, I would also like to see a simple Insight query example so I can build on that.

Anyone help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you put in the bits of code you have till now... The logging is the same as the python logging we usually write in python. What is the format you are looking for.. Examples would be helpful

Comment: Added a code snippet, hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the sames as setting up a simple logger

Simple sample below

```
MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=MSG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger('Something')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Then your code

```
start = timeit.default_timer()

...run some code

stop = timeit.default_timer()

runtime = stop - start

logger.info('Runtime: {}'.format(runtime))
```

Comment: What would the query for CloudWatch Insights be for this? That's what I'm confused with @Emerson

Comment: have u tried
```
fields @timestamp, @message 
| filter @message like "Runtime"
```

Comment: `fields @timestamp, @message | filter @message like "Something"` works, not "Runtime". What I am looking for is to have fields like @Runtime show the runtime value in this case.

Comment: ``fields @timestamp,@message | parse @message " [*] * *: *" as level, loggername, exception | filter @exception like "RunTime"```

Comment: ``fields @timestamp,@message | parse @message " [*] *: *" as level, loggername, exception | filter @exception like "RunTime"```
sorry i thin i added an extra asterix

Comment: Still doesn't work, I switched the @exception to "Something" and tried that as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211030/discussion-between-emerson-and-codingenthusiast).

Comment: Glue logs are a dump from their yarn/spark exuections and this means that the logs you want is part of a execution log line in cloud watch. This makes it hard to parse and retrieve the information that you want especially since your log line has newline characters in it

Comment: A possible solution would be to send your log as a stream to s3, and then put those log messages onto cloudwatch and run insights off them. That way your log messages wont be mixed up with the rest of the glue messages that get dumped into cloudwatch

Comment: Or better yet, try directly putting custom events within your glue code using boto3 and then running insights out of that log group